# Firebase Record Exists but unable to retrieve Data from Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase Table Field Structure Image attached for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ke8G.png)

What I want ? Simply want to fetch all fields data (like City, Phone and others)

I'm damn sure, I need to make some changes in below line of code:

```
PaidUsers paidUsers = dataSnapshot.getValue(PaidUsers.class);
```

This is the code, I'm using to check whether data exists or not correspondent to uPhone (and it works just well, checked with registered and unregistered phone numbers) and found implementation is correct

```
private void fetchAndPopulateData() {

    databaseReference.orderByChild("uPhone").equalTo(uPhone).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    // getting called

                    PaidUsers paidUsers = dataSnapshot.getValue(PaidUsers.class);
                    uPhone = paidUsers.getuPhone();
                    uCity = paidUsers.getuCity();

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), uPhone+"_"+uCity, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                    // getting null_null

            } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Snackbar.make(getView(), "Create your Profile", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled Called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}
```

but unable to retrieve data from Firebase's PaidUsers table, as you can see below, I'm trying to get uPhone and uCity, but did not get anything, may I know why, where I am doing mistake?:

```
                PaidUsers paidUsers = dataSnapshot.getValue(PaidUsers.class);
                uPhone = paidUsers.getuPhone();
                uCity = paidUsers.getuCity();

                Snackbar.make(getView(), uPhone+"_"+uCity, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                // getting null_null
```

I'm getting none of the value, Is there anything I'm missing ?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please log it line by line.

Comment: You're missing an `onCancelled` which may provide a clue.

Comment: please check again I posted updated code and firebase database table structure for more clarity

Comment: Please add a cleaner db schema. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.